# how do I set my virtual disk's memory to 0

Tags: c

```
static int fd;
int make_disk(char *name){
    int cnt;
    char buf[BLOCK_SIZE];

    fd = open(name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);

    memset(buf, 0, (BLOCK_SIZE * DISK_BLOCKS));
    for(cnt = 0; cnt < BLOCK_SIZE; ++cnt){
        write(fd, buf, DISK_BLOCKS);
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code, I couldn't figure out why memset function won't work in here.

Comment: What does "*won't work*" mean? Also your `buf` has size `BLOCK_SIZE`, not `BLOCK_SIZE * DISK_BLOCKS`. One or the other is wrong.

Comment: ... and you need to check if `open` fails.

Comment: so basically the buf size is a issue and I fixed it. The memset functions won't work because it won't initialize the memory of the created disk to 0.

Comment: @aaron how do you know if `open` succeeds?

Comment: i didn't see your comment when I reply to uneven_mark. So, I add an if statement to check if it succeeds.

Comment: I think he wants to mmap file.

Comment: @aaron... and? Does it succeed?? Also [edit] your question and show the _actual code_, also show how you call `make_disk`

Comment: @aaron Please add error checks to `open` and `write`, show *how* you fixed the buffer size mismatch and then explain how exactly the program doesn't work. What *does* it write to the file? Does the program finish correctly without error or does it segfault?

Answer (score 0):

> This is my code, I couldn't figure out why memset function won't work in here.

You have an array of `BLOCK_SIZE` bytes and you are trying to set all `BLOCK_SIZE*DISK_BLOCKS` bytes in that array to 0. I assume that `DISK_BLOCKS` is more than 1, so `memset` gets to the end of the array and then keeps going because you told it to.

Comment: yeah, I finally fixed it. I get confused with the block size and the number of blocks that I defined in my header file. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want mmaped file

`char *map = mmap(0, BLOCK_SIZE * DISK_BLOCKS, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);`

and then

```
memset(map, 0, (BLOCK_SIZE * DISK_BLOCKS));
msync(map, (BLOCK_SIZE * DISK_BLOCKS), MS_SYNC);
```